# SSIS: Manage broken Data Flow Task because Excel column name changed?

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-data-tools

I have a simple SSIS package that exports an Excel file to a csv file: each column in the Excel is mapped to a column in the csv.

Assuming that a column name in the Excel file changes, is it possible to *gracefully* manage this error so that it's marked as "failure" in the `Precedence Constraint Editor` and then moves on to the *Failure* task?

As it stands, if I run the package with a different column name, I'll get this error and everything stops:
[image]

I'd like to edit it so that if the column changes, it goes to the "Send Failure Email" task.
Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is this.

This will then only validate when it reaches the task and not when the package initializes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The Connection Manager's `DelayValidation` will save you when the source file doesn't yet exist (say you have to download/copy the file first). While a useful one to set as True, fdkgfosfskjdlsjdlkfsf will also need to set the DelayValidation property on their Data Flow to True as well.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that even if it runs, the error won't be managed. I'll still get the Package Validation Error from SSIS instead of just capturing it and moving to the "On Failure" Task.

Comment: @billinkc: Your comment and Inus C's answer did the trick. Thanks.